# Стили для содержимиого iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Есть у меня `<iframe>`, есть ли способы в изменять стили его содержимого? Поменять стили в самой страничке, которая подгружается в iframe нет возможности

Comment: Если страница в iframe загружается с того же домена, что и основная страница, то можно на js добавить в iframe какой-нибудь класс для стилизации. Если же страница на другом домене, то нет, нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, сделать что-то типа такого:

```
$('iframe').load( function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find("head")
      .append($("<style type='text/css'>  .test{color: red;}  </style>"));
});
```

Но только для iframe который находится на твоем домене, в другом случае браузер не даст тебе этого сделать.
Почитай: [CSS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)